# Adyen v5.51.0 Credit Card Web Component: Is `onFieldValid` Still Functional?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, adyen

I'm currently working on a project that utilizes the Adyen credit card web component (version 5.51.0).

Here's the configuration I'm using:

```js
const configuration = {
    locale: "en_US",
    environment: "test",
    clientKey: "test_ABCDEFG",
    analytics: {
        enabled: false
    },
    paymentMethodsResponse: myPaymentMethodsResponse,
    onChange: handleOnChange,
    paymentMethodsConfiguration: {
        card: {
            styles: styleObject,
            hasHolderName: true,
            holderNameRequired: false,
        }
    },
    onFieldValid: handleFieldValidation,
};

function handleFieldValidation(data) {
    // my code
}
```

I've noticed that the `onFieldValid` function doesn't seem to be working as expected. I'm wondering if this function is still operational in version 5.51.0, or if I might be implementing it incorrectly. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

[Screenshot from Adyen Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WKoF.png)

Trying to use the onFieldValid event.

Answer (score 1):

The `onFieldValid` should be declared in the `paymentMethodsConfiguration` for the `card` payment method, instead of placing it at the root (global) level:

```
  paymentMethodsConfiguration: {
    card: {
      styles: styleObject,
       hasHolderName: true,
       holderNameRequired: false,
       onFieldValid : (state, component) => {
         handleFieldValidation(state, component)
       },
```

[Here](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/cards/web-drop-in/) you can find all configuration options for cards in the Drop-in integration.